# How to parse Postgresql 'Infinity' timestamp in R2JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, r2dbc

How to parse `infinity` in R2JDBC?  Getting the following error

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'infinity' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954) ~[na:na]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.PostgresqlDateTimeFormatter.parse(PostgresqlDateTimeFormatter.java:103
```